# How do I display a page at a specific section in .NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Sorry if this is a stupid question or has been asked before, but I've been looking for an hour and haven't found any answers. 
I'm working on a .NET Core MVC web application, and one of the views has subsections that I want to be able to go to directly, without having to have already loaded the view.

If the view is loaded, then `href="viewname.html#sectionID"` works, but it won't work if I am currently on another view. It also confuses me that my view files are .cshtml, and not plain HTML files, and it still recognizes which section of the view it needs to go to...
I tried using the Anchor Tag Helper and I couldn't figure out how I would do it with that.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: cshtml are razor views. Its a templating engine use in ASP.NET Core (among with Razor Pages which are not backed up by a controller but have code tied to the "code behind" of the page). You can use a mixture of html (fragments, the main layout is in _Layout.cshtml) and C#/Razor Syntax to put logic into your views or pages. [See Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1).  `#` is an anchor and not really part of an url (never sent to a server). It jumps to an html element with the `id="sectionID"` attribute.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question though, do you want to know hot to generate the link to it?

Comment: @Tseng That jump to an html element is exactly what I want. I have a drop-down menu that has different entries. All of those entries redirect to the same view, but I want them to redirect to different sections/html elements within that view(i.e. not just redirecting to the top of that view).

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work the way I wanted it by mix and matching `href="ViewName#sectionID"` for when I want to go to a specific section in the view, using `href` only calls for all views except the homepage one and `asp-action="ViewName"` for the homepage view(index). Also, I defined the routes for the controller actions for every action other than the homepage. This way, the URL is basically always `myURL.com/ViewName/`, and on the homepage it's just `myURL.com/`, so an `href` that specifies the URL will lead to the desired controller action.

This is pretty basic, and it was just my lack of understanding towards how routing worked, but maybe someone else runs into this and finds this answer useful... I do feel pretty dumb though.